# Prestashop product image swap on thumbnail click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prestashop

Every product has the posibility to have several images, those images are listed as a list to the left of the main product image.

The problem I have is when the user clicks on any of the thumbs, it get's the image but on a modal box, not swaping over the main image. Just like this [example](http://shop.garancedore.fr/collections/art-prints/products/early-winter-1)

Any guide/ideas how to achieve this on Prestashop?

I have already asked this on the Prestashop forum, with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that big image block is positioned over thumbnails images,
so script can not register hover event over thumbnails. Fix is easy, change 
in theme/default/css product.css line 15 code to

```
#pb-right-column #image-block {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```